# C++ Qt doesnt work SetNum and setEnabled

Tags: c++, qt

```
void MainWindow::on_ParceButton_clicked()
{
    ui->ParceButton->setEnabled(false);
    int thr = ui->lineEdit4->text().toInt();
    ifstream inp_tmp("AllTempLinks.txt");
    runnedth=0;

    QNetworkAccessManager *nmanager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    connect(nmanager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(FinishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
    string link;
    while(getline(inp_tmp,link))
    {
        QUrl req = QUrl(QString::fromStdString(link));

        while(runnedth >= thr)
        {
            QApplication::processEvents();
        }

        QNetworkReply* reply = nmanager->get(QNetworkRequest(req));
        ui->label_6->setNum(totalglinks);
    }


    inp_tmp.close();
    ui->ParceButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

All request ended successfully, but ui->label_6->setNum(totalglinks); dont work. And when my function called, ParceButton remains active.

Comment: Where is `totalglinks` set?  What do you mean it "dont work", it shows the wrong number, no number, garbage?

Comment: Its int variable. But this value not changet in window

Comment: Is your `QApplication::processEvents()` inside `while` called at all?

Comment: It will be run out until the maximum number of threads running

Comment: What this code is suposed to do? Please explain the logic.

Comment: 1) potential memory leak on 'nmanager'; 2) check the content of 'totalglinks' before setting it to labels

Comment: This code readed from file urls and do request on this url (with entered qty of threads), after it increment "totalglinks" in FinishedSlot function and display it in window. But it not displayed. Urls is correctly (FinishedSlot do other iterations good, and increment maybe too). And ParceButton all time is enabled, but it try do disable it when my function is running

Comment: I think my program firstly execute beginning of the function after end of the function and then after the middle. Because if i past "delete nmanager;" program dont do requests to urls. Or no?

Comment: If you're doing multi-threading, it is not a good idea to do heavy/blocking tasks at the main GUI thread.

Comment: Maybe u have any links where i can get more information about good multi-threading coding?